# How to iterate though an arraylist and copy certain objects that match a criteria to another arraylist?

Tags: java, loops, class, arraylist, package

I have a class called Personality, that contains variables like name, sport and votes. I have another class called Competition that stores these personality objects in an arraylist.

I have to write a method in the competition class to find the desired number of personality objects in the arraylist that have the highest number of votes and save them to a new arraylist in the order from most votes to least.

For example, entering the int 5 to the method will create an array list storing the 5 personality objects from the original arraylist with the most votes.

Is there a java package that contains a pre-written class that can do atleast some of this for me?

Comment: ArrayList has a copy constructor, and it has a sort() method, and it has a subList() method. So it has all you need for the task you want. Read its javadoc. That's true for any class you use: you must read its documentation to know what you can do with it.

Comment: please write an example of use